# How to change dynamically the render of icons inside a table based on a type of the data coming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I'm new to React I have some difficulties to make a functional component which essentially should change dynamically the render of an icon based on a type getting from data.

The table itself already exist and it is mapped and getting inside all the data I need.

In one row/cell I have to include an Icon component which pass the type and also I need to have `onClick` function here

```
 <TableCell>
    <Icon rowType={row.type} onClick={<some function>}/>
 </TableCell>
```

The `row.type` is a type of a specific data I'm getting and I need to focus on 2 types

- SLOT
- SITE

Based on this 2 types I have to render a SLOT_ICON and a SITE_ICON in the table when in a row I have one of those two.

I thought to make an `if/elseif` but I actually don't know how to render and how also to include then the onClick event based on which icon I'm clicking.

A pseudo code example:

```
const Icon = rowType => {
    if (rowType === 'SLOT') {
      SLOT;
    } else if (rowType === 'SITE') {
      SITE;
    }

    <-- onClick logic somewhere here? -->
    return Icon
  };
```

Comment: A google search for `'React Conditional Rendering'` will bring you a lot of possible solutions

Comment: If you want a full answer, please include the code you're using to render each type of icon.

Comment: I don't have any code about it I can include full code of the table but Icons is the new part  I have difficulties to do

Comment: If icons are not SVG images, you simply have to return an `<img />` tag from your Icon component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering in react.

```
const Icon = ({ type, onClick }) => {
    if (type === "SLOT") return <img src={"slot"} onClick={onClick} />;
    else if (type === "SITE") return <img src={"site"} onClick={onClick} />;
    else return <img src={"icon"} onClick={onClick} />;
  };
```

You can use `Icon` as follows

```
<Icon type="SLOT" onClick={() => {}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is you will probably end up having something like this (please notice I made quite a lot of assumptions about your code therefore you might have to tune the example provided):

#### parent component:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import TableCell from '/path/to/component/';
import Icon from '/path/to/component/';

const ParentComponent = ({row, ...props}) => {
  //...
  const onIconClick = useCallback(() => {
    //do whatever you have to do
  }, [ /*dependencies*/ ]);

  return (
    <TableCell>
      <Icon rowType={row.type} onClick={onIconClick} />
    </TableCell>
  );
}
```

#### Icon component:

```
import React, { useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';

const Icon = ({rowType, onClick}) => {
  const iconData = useMemo(() => {
    const basePath = '/path/to/image/folder/';
    switch (rowType) {
        case 'SLOT':
          return {
            src: basePath + 'slotFile.ext',
            alt: 'slot alternative text'
          };
        case 'SITE':
          return {
            src: basePath + 'siteFile.ext',
            alt: 'site alternative text'
          };
        default:
          return null;
    }
  }, [rowType]);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    // 1. do whatever additional operation you have to do (if any)
    // ...
    // 2. execute the function passed by the parent
    onClick();
  }, []);

  return iconData ? (
    <img
      src={iconData.src}
      alt={iconData.alt}
      onClick={() => handleClick()}
    />
  ) : null;
}

export default Icon;
```